# Finding a return value while passing n variables in a method

Tags: java, arrays

```
int add3(int...numbers)
{
    for(int number : numbers)
    {
        int number1=0;
        number1= number+number1;
    }
    return number1;
}
```

This is what I have written to find out the summation of n numbers while being passed through a method. I am getting an error while getting the return value i.e. the number1 variable cannot be resolved to a variable type.

Comment: Variable1 is a local variable inside the loop, you can´t reference it outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare number1 before the loop. If you define it inside the loop, it is not recognized after the loop, in the return statement.

```
int add3(int...numbers)
{
    int number1=0;
    for(int number : numbers)
    {   
        number1= number+number1;
    }
    return number1;
}
```

Another suggestion is to change `number1` to a meaningful name, such as `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

For each number you are declaring `int number1` within the loop

```
int add3(int...numbers)
{
    for(int number : numbers)
    {
        int number1=0;// each time you r declaring this
        number1= number+number1;//number1 = 0 + number all the time. so you will not get summation of numbers 
    }
    return number1;//compiler error will be there because no declaration for number1 for out of the loop
}
```

So declare number1 outside of the loop:

```
int add3(int...numbers)
{
    int number1=0;
    for(int number : numbers)
    {
        number1= number+number1;
    }
    return number1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about [variable scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html).

`number1` is a local variable inside the loop, you can´t reference it outside of it. Instead declare `number1` outside the `for` loop like:

```
int add3(int...numbers)
{
    int number1=0;
    for(int number : numbers)
    {   
        number1= number+number1;
    }
    return number1;
}
```

Now the *scope* of `number1` is the whole `add3` function and hence it can be referenced anywhere inside the function.